# use count_all_results from query

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

i have complex query and say it $complexQuery,
then i need to get all data row number from that without need the data result.

I researched that count_all_results() i better than num_rows()

now say my code :

```
$complexQuery = 'Some sql query';
$q = $this->db->query($complexQuery);
$total1 = $q->num_rows();
```

now i confuse to get all total data from that query,
any suggestion for using $this->db->count_all_results() with that query ?

== SOLVED BY EDITING DB_active_rec.php ==

i do this (leave as it is if tablename contained 'select') :

```
public function from($from)
{
    foreach ((array)$from as $val)
    {
        if (strpos($val, ',') !== FALSE)
        {
            foreach (explode(',', $val) as $v)
            {
                $v = trim($v);
                $this->_track_aliases($v);
                $v = $this->ar_from[] = $this->_protect_identifiers($v, TRUE, NULL, FALSE);

                if ($this->ar_caching === TRUE)
                {
                    $this->ar_cache_from[] = $v;
                    $this->ar_cache_exists[] = 'from';
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $val = trim($val);

            // Added to bypass from arr if $val contained 'select' for complex query
            // $this->db->count_all_rows("select * from tableName")
            // will be select count(1) from (select * from tableName)
            if(FALSE !== strpos(strtolower($val),'select')){
                $this->ar_from[] = "($val)";
            }else{
                // Extract any aliases that might exist. We use this information
                // in the _protect_identifiers to know whether to add a table prefix
                $this->_track_aliases($val);
                $this->ar_from[] = $val = $this->_protect_identifiers($val, TRUE, NULL, FALSE);
            }

            if ($this->ar_caching === TRUE)
            {
                $this->ar_cache_from[] = $val;
                $this->ar_cache_exists[] = 'from';
            }
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: what do you wnat can you explain?

Comment: @user2020329 how did you solve it? where is the php file?

Answer (score 1):

that should be like:

```
$this->db->where($complexQuery);
$this->db->from('your_table_name');
echo $this->db->count_all_results();
```

See: [Codeigniter count_all_results()](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)

Comment: i cannot .. all query will be inside $complexQuery,
there will be any table and join table inside it.

Answer (score 0):

another minutes, but the same code

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

      class SomeMyModel extends CI_Model {

      private static $db;

      function __construct() 
      {
        parent::__construct();
        self::$db = &get_instance()->db;
      }

        static function countTableResults(){
          self::$db->where($coplexQuery);
           return self::$db->count_all_results('#TABLENAME#');
        }
```